# relative path in data source in unittesting

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I wrote a unit test which use the `data source` attribute.
Until now I have been using the **full path** but I want to replace it with **relative path**.

but the running of the testing executed from the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe** and use my unit test as **dll**.
and I want the relative path from the location of the unit test.

use methods or prop like `Environment.CurrentDirectory` throw compile error:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression 
or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
```

I found also the variable |`DataDirectory`| but It doesn't come with the true path.

**for example**:

```
my unit test location is
c:\theproject\source\test\unittest\MyUnitTest.dll
and my excel file location is
c:\theproject\source\test\helpfiles\MyExcelFile.xlsx
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I try to use again the

```
|DataDirectory|
```

property and it works,
maybe the raleted path wasn't right...